# Relation rules in MySql

Tags: sql, mysql

How do I define relation rules in mysql?

Table1:
  bookId authorId bookName

Table2:
 authorId authorName

This is how I would like the Mysql server to behave: When I try to insert a row into table1 with a authorId that doesn't exsist in table2, mysql would produce a error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to define authorid as a foreign key. You need to do something like this:

```
Alter Table Table1 Add Foreign Key (authorid) References Table2 (authorid);
```

Make sure your tables are innodb because it won't work on myisam tables. You can find the documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html).